# What's the difference between 'secret_id_key' and 'ed25519_master_id_key'?

Tags: relays, directory, node, private-key, key

I'm running a TOR relay and I'm confused with the node identity keys. The secret_id_key is the identity key that was used in version 2, but now the ed25519_master_id_key is used for version 3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`secret_id_key` is an RSA key and `ed25519_master_id_key` is a Ed25519 key used for Hidden Services v3.

Here is what the spec says about it: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec-v3.txt#n127

> 0.1. Improvements over previous versions.
>
> Here is a list of improvements of this proposal over the legacy hidden
> services:
>
> - **Better crypto (replaced SHA1/DH/RSA1024 with SHA3/ed25519/curve25519)**
> - Improved directory protocol leaking less to directory servers.
> - Improved directory protocol with smaller surface for targeted attacks.
> - Better onion address security against impersonation.
> - More extensible introduction/rendezvous protocol.
> - Offline keys for onion services
> - Advanced client authorization